# How to get an li to expand to fit thumbnail content?

Tags: css, list, gallery, thumbnails

I realize this question (or questions that look like this) have been asked over and over and I feel like I've read all of them with no avail.  I'm new to this so bear with me and it could be that through this frustration I've forgotten a fundamental nature of the list elements. Here's my issue...

I have a thumbnail gallery with thumbs of different sizes (I'm dynamically loading thumbs from a folder upon page load).  The thumbnail gallery is made using an ul.  When I set the il's property to inline so that they run back to back and not in a list the li's don't expand to fit the thumbs within.  If I change the li display back to block (or remove display) they then expand to fit the contents... If I use display: inline-block the li content thumbs shrink to fit the li but then the li's are still wider than the images...arg!

How do I tell the il to expand to fit the contents without specifying a size?

Here's my CSS:

```
.gallery {
width: 100%;
cursor: default;

overflow:hidden;
}
.gallery ul {
list-style:none outside none;
overflow:hidden;
}
.gallery li {
background: #eee;
border-color: #ddd #bbb #aaa #ccc;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
color: inherit; 

margin: 3px;
padding: 5px;   

display:inline; 
position: relative;
vertical-align:top;

overflow:hidden;
}
```

here's a sample of the code after it loads:

```
<div class="gallery">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="brown.png"><img src="/photos/brown.png" alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="blue.png"><img src="/photos/blue.png" alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="light-blue.png"><img src="./photos/light-blue.png" alt="" /></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

So when I view the page I see something like the following:

```
         __             __
<   ----|  |----   ----|  |----
<   ----|__|----   ----|__|----
```

The center boxes represent the img elements and the smaller dashed rectangles in the background are the parent li elements. (sorry I couldn't post a pic because I'm a newbie :))

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Could you maybe add links to a couple of the actual images? (Ideally use [imgur](http://imgur.com/), or similar, then it'll not hurt your server.) Incidentally [no-repro on JS Fiddle, with `display: inline-block;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r5Sy6/). The `li` is larger than the `img`, but only because of the `padding` you specify.

Comment: haven't you answered yourself? `"If I change the li display back to block (or remove display) they then expand to fit the contents..."`. please be more specific. what's the problem?

Comment: David: The image is here http://i.imgur.com/2Pdho.jpg

Comment: Eliran - Sorry I should have been more specific - when I change it back to block yes the li element then expands to fit the img but it also then expands to fill the row see img here http://imgur.com/aRkom

Comment: Doh! - David thanks!! - I just looked at the code you put on JS Fiddle and and couldn't figure it out but when I changed display to inline-block it worked.  Seriously I thought I tried inline-block at some point in the last million changes - oh well it works now :)  Thanks so Much for the reply!!!

Comment: you'll need to be aware of the behavior of `inline-block`. test for cross-browser compatibility (test on IE7/8, on opera, safari and see if anything breaks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David thanks!! - I just looked at the code you put on JS Fiddle and and couldn't figure it out but when I changed display to inline-block it worked. Seriously I thought I tried inline-block at some point in the last million changes - oh well it works now :) Thanks so Much for the reply!!!